# NSScrollView and ScrollToPoint on an NSImage

Tags: cocoa, nsimage, nsscrollview

I have a NSView as the documentView for a NSScrollView. I also have a NSImageView as a subview of the NSView. The image dynamically changes size so the scroll bars become active/inactive at various times. Once the image has changed, I'd like to scroll to a certain point on the image. From within the NSView's drawRect: method, I call
    [[myScrollView contentView] scrollToPoint: myPoint];

The scroll bars update and the image appears as I'd like, but as soon as the image is scrolled, a double image appears or parts of the image get cut off. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you scrolling within `-drawRect:`? You shouldn't do anything but draw and definitely not stuff which will call any `-setNeedsDisplay...` methods.

Comment: My next attempt at fixing this issue was to set the image and documentView frame outside of the -drawRect method. I'll give that a try

Comment: You were right. As soon as I moved the setFrame, setOrigin, scrollToPoint, etc methods out of -drawRect everything worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might want to turn off the "Copy On Scroll" behavior option of the `NSScrollView` either in Interface Builder or programmatically.

From [Scroll View Programming Guide for Mac OS X: How Scrolling Works](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003461-SW10):

> The `NSClipView` class provides low-level scrolling support through the
>   `scrollToPoint:` method. This method translates the origin of the
>   content view’s bounds rectangle and optimizes redisplay by copying as
>   much of the rendered document view as remains visible, only asking the
>   document view to draw newly exposed regions. This usually improves
>   scrolling performance but may not always be appropriate. You can turn
>   this behavior off using the `NSClipView` method `setCopiesOnScroll:`
>   passing `NO` as the parameter. If you do leave copy-on-scroll active, be
>   sure to scroll the document view programmatically using the `NSView`
>   method `scrollPoint:` method rather than `translateOriginToPoint:`.

Comment: Tried setting this in IB and it kinda worked. Will try a combo of this and setting the documentView frame outside of the -drawRect method. Thank you!